# Function as parameter in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, mathematica, finite-differences

I want to define some basic functions known from "discrete analysis":

$$I(f)(x):=f(x)$$
$$E(f)(x):=f(x+1)$$
$$\Delta(f)(x) := (E-I)(f)(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$$
$$\nabla(f)(x) := (I-E^{-1})(f)(x) = f(x)-f(x-1)$$

And I know that I can define a function `f[x_] := x^2` like that, but how can I take a function and evaluate it at the given position like `E[fn_] := evaluate fn at x+1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) command to make a definition such as `Eval[f_,x_]:= Apply[f,{x}]`  (you can't use `E` as the name of your function, though - this is reserved by Mathematica for the number $e=2.71828\ldots$).

For example:

```
F[x_]:=x^2+1
Eval[f_,x_]:= Apply[f,{x}]

Eval[F,5]=26
Eval[F,x+1]=1+(1+x)^2
Eval[F,x]=1+x^2
```

Then you can define

```
Delta[g_]:=FullSimplify[Eval[g,x+1]-Eval[g,x]]
Delta[F]=1+2x
```

Comment: It does not work like expected! E.g. $E(f)(x)$ is now called `TranslateEx`. `TranslateEx[fn_] := Apply[fn, {x + 1}]` and then `TranslateEx[x]` leads to the result `x[1 + x]`. What does this mean? I expected `x + 1` as the result. **EDIT** It seems i cannot enter a function directly and i need to specify it explicitly...

Comment: @Christian: `x` by itself *is not a function*. You need to define a function `g[x_]:=x`, and *then* you can do `TranslateEx[g]=1+x`.

Comment: Is there any way, like in programming languages, to define an "anonymous function" (a.k.a. lambda-expression) the way i tried?

Comment: You might be able to do it [with the `Function` command](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), but I'm not familiar with it myself.

Comment: eval[k_][f_]:=f[k]

Answer (score 6):

Actually, for *Mathematica* 7 and later versions, you have the functions `Identity[]`, `DiscreteShift[]`, and `DifferenceDelta[]`:

```
Identity[f[x]]
f[x]

DiscreteShift[f[x], x]
f[1 + x]

DifferenceDelta[f[x], x]
-f[x] + f[1 + x]
```

The backward difference needs a bit more work:

```
DifferenceDelta[DiscreteShift[f[x], {x, 1, -1}], x]
-f[-1 + x] + f[x]
```

Otherwise:

```
bdf[f_, x_] := f - (f /. x -> x - 1)

bdf[f[x], x]
-f[-1 + x] + f[x]
```

In fact, *Mathematica* supports more traditional notation (see the manual for details):

[image: shifts and differences]